# Migration from iOS 5 to iOS 6 possible issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I've heard that there might be some issues with this, but haven't found any official announcements. Is it possible to release a new version of an app to AppStore where previous version was supporting iOS 5.1 and the new one supports iOS 6.0 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue at all. Simply change the Deployment Target setting for your project and submit an update. People have updated apps for the last 4 years by changing the minimum supported version of iOS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if it's all cool when uploading the app to AppStore and will accept your answer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the changes deal with syntax that has been outdated, and xCode's automatic correction/terminal will supply you with the newly required methods & such. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

only known to me is : orientation handling in a new way... this is to be changed in older code...

```
// iOS 5 interface orientation handling
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

//iOS6 interface orientation handling

- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

The should rotate method is deprecated and will no longer be called as of iOS 6, but it was not meant to be used the way you were using it anyway.